# Using Treeview as a dropdown template for combo with complex grouping requirments

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Using the data below as an example...

```
Id      Name                Type        Sector
12345   GOOG                Eqty        Internet
12346   MSFT                Eqty        Internet
12347   MOBL                Eqty        Oil
12348   XOM                 Eqty        Oil
12349   Wheat               Comdty          
12310   Corn                Comdty          
12311   Nas 100 eMini       Futures             
12312   S&P 500 eMini       Futures
```

Using the above data i want to build a dropdown combo selector w/ autofiltering that will display a treeview in the format shown below.
Essentially, i want to group by "Type", then by "Sector", then display the Name.  However if Sector is missing, then Name should be grouped under just Type.

```
+Equities(Eqty)
    +Internet
        Goog
        Msft
    +Oil
        MOBL
        XOM
+Commodities(Comdty)
    Wheat
    Corn
+Futures
    Nas 100 eMini
    S&P 500 eMini
```

I've tried a number of ways to do this elegantly via just XAML/templating, without much luck.  The complicated part here is that the second grouping is conditional.
Any thoughts on how i might be able to solve this issue would be appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for a templated solution or just anything that works ?

Comment: A templated solution would be preferable...but at this point anything that works.  i've started building a usercontrol to try and do this.  it looks like i'll have to build the object hierarchy and use a hierarchical data template.

Comment: I ended up doing most of this w/ code behind.  initially i was generating a parent/child hierarchy in code, then attempting to render that using a hierachical data template.  but now, i'm using that same code to just simply add the treviewitems to the treeview. not elegant, but works

Comment: I was going to suggest that you create your data hierarchy in code behind and then use a hierarchial template, but it seems you've worked it out.

Comment: autofiltering by what? the Name?

Answer (score -1):

If you are intent on working with the now defunct technology called SilverLight and therein use XAML ? Templating look at [this link for recursive templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299915/are-recursive-datatemplates-possible)

To do this using linq, what you need is a recursive call... see [the answer given here for a nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409021/id-parentid-list-to-hierarchical-list).

Comment: no not using silverlight, but am using WPF/Xaml.  Is XAML or silverlight now defunct?

Comment: There are many rumours around that the entire silverlight team have migrated to work on Windows 8, and that the death of Silverlight is therefore assured as an implementation of XAML presentation. And it follows logically that WPF may also be going the same way. Therein even if it is only a widely accepted rumour at the moment, rumours like this do cause things to die a death http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt I believe that XAML has it's place in Windows 8... but as to the future of SilverLight and WPF, MS are being suspiciously quiet about the matter.